# Where does the electricity in electromagnets come from if permanent magnets from generators decrease their magnetic strength?

Tags: electromagnetism, generator, solar-energy, magnet, electromagnet

The question has been puzzling me for some time, I presume electrical power starts from generators, the heat produced by them(generators) cause their magnets to weaken and electromagnets have to be used instead.

Where does the electricity to make electromagnets come from yet power (presumably) starts from generators?

I could think about solar panels but the sun isn't shining all the time.

Comment: Generators do use permanent magnets usually.

Comment: In a car, the battery energises the alternator field coil in order to make it produce power (and regulate the voltage).

Answer (score 1):

Large generators use electromagnets as large magnets can be made stronger as electromagnets.

A large modern generator includes a device called an exciter which is a small generator on the same shaft to make the current to excite the main generator. The this is controlled by a device called an Automatic Voltage Regulator in order to control the main generator voltage.

The power for the exciter either comes from the residual magnetism of the main generator making a little bit of electricity or from an even smaller permanent magnet generator linked to the shaft. The HF generator in the diagram below.

[image]